# Update patch edge colours in Geopandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I've plotted a GeoDataFrame as a choropleth using the following code (geopandas 0.2.1, matplotlib 2.0.2, in a Jupyter notebook, using `%inline`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    1,
    figsize=(16., 12.),
    dpi=100,
    subplot_kw=dict(aspect='equal'),
)

base = imd_gdf.dropna().plot(
    ax=ax,
    alpha=1.,
    column="Rental_Count",
    scheme="fisher_jenks",
    k=7,
    cmap="viridis",
    linewidth=0.1,
    edgecolor='black',
    legend=True,
)
```

Which gives me a map with edges around the polygons:

[image]

I'd like to remove these. So far, I've tried cycling through the patches, setting the edge colours to the face colours:

```
for p in ax.patches:
    nc = p.get_facecolor()
    p.set_edgecolor(nc)
```

But it has no effect, even if I specify a single colour in the loop. Neither `p.set_color(nc)`, or attempting to set the line width to 0 using `p.set_linewidth(0.0)` have any effect.
What am I missing here? Updating the face colour in the same way using `p.set_facecolor('white')` works fine:

[image]

Comment: what happens when you set the edge color to the string `"none"` in your original call to the `plot` method?

Comment: @PaulH setting it to `'none'` causes the edges to be drawn as white

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that `plot()` draws a collection of line objects (the `lines` property of the `AxesSubplot`, they're `lines.Line2D`) which represent the actual edges. Updating these **as well as** the edge properties of the patches (`AxesSubplot.patches`) is necessary if you want full control of the edge appearance.

## Update, April 2022

Newer Geopandas versions (0.10+) have an additional [`missing_kwds`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/mapping.html?highlight=missing_kwds#missing-data) dict which can be passed to the `plot()` function, in order to draw geometries which have `NaN` values for the given input `column` argument, when drawing a choropleth. This results in a new child `PatchCollection` being drawn, and it's *always* (as of this version, so that could change?) the **second** child of `ax._children`.

In order to modify how these two separate `PatchCollections` are drawn, then, you have to do something like the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(..., missing_kwds={facecolor='#000000'}, ...)
df.plot(...)
# NaN polygons
c = ax._children[1]
c.set_edgecolors(#000000) # match the facecolor in missing_kwds
c.set_zorder(1) # this ensures it's drawn last

# Drawn polygons
c2 = ax._children[0]
c2.set_edgecolors(retained_ec)
c2.set_zorder(2) # this ensures it's drawn first

# now call plt.savefig, plt.show etc
```

Comment: How do you get access to lines.Line2D? Thank you

Comment: @MorningGlory No idea whether you ever figured it out, but I posted an update that may help if not